# fill BufferedReader with data

Tags: java, bufferedreader

All examples I find are filling the BufferedReader from files. I need to fill it with data from a "for" loop like this:

```
List<Nodes> nodes; //there are data here
BufferedReader bufRead = null;
for (Node node : nodes) {   
    //need to fill the BufferedReader with node data line by line    
    bufRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(null, node.toString()+"\n"));    
}
//use the BufferedReader later on
```

Comment: Why? You already have the data. What good is putting it into a `BfferedReader` going to do you? It's just a waste of time and space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "fill" a [`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html). *Reader* is a verb, saying that it *reads* something, so you have to provide the source that is being read from.

If you have Java code that generates text, which you later want to read, then use e.g. a [`StringWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) to write the text into a memory buffer. You can then later read that text using e.g. a [`StringReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html).

*Example*

```
String text;
try (StringWriter strOut = new StringWriter()) {
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(strOut)) {
        for (Node node : nodes) {
            out.println(node);
        }
    }
    text = strOut.toString();
}

try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(text))) {
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        // use line here
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

> *From comment:* I was wondering if there is a more "elegant", shorter solution

The use of `PrintWriter` is of course optional, and with the `String` versions of `Reader` and `Writer`, there is really no need to call `close()`.

```
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
for (Node node : nodes) {
    out.write(node + "\n");
}

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(out.toString()));
for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
    // use line here
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead.

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (Node node : nodes) {
    buf.append(node).append('\n');
}

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(buf.toString()));
for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
    // use line here
}
```

Comment: It works fine. I was wondering if there is a more "elegand", shorter solution before I mark it as the correct answer....